# Is there a way to personally disable the pre-logon Windows 10 services nag?

Tags: windows-10

I'm speaking of this screen, which now appears every other time I boot up my PC, that I must acknowledge to even be allowed to log in. I am using Windows 10 Professional version 1903.

[image]

Comment: Can you check what your user account folder is called under `C:\Users`? This seems like something that would happen if you were only logging on to a temporary profile.

Comment: @MichaelFrank It's my standard user account. There are no temporary profiles on the system.

Answer (score 1):

**First method**

1. Open **Settings** (Win + I)
2. Go to System > Notifications & actions, on the right, uncheck the option **"Suggest ways I can finish setting up my device to get the most out of Windows."** (may be a slightly different text on your version)

**Second method**

1. Open the Registry Editor app (regedit.exe).
2. Go to the Registry key
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\UserProfileEngagement`.
3. On the right, modify or create a new 32-Bit DWORD value named `ScoobeSystemSettingEnabled`.
4. Set its value data to **0** to disable the screen.
5. Sign out and then sign back in to your account

From [WinAero](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-get-even-more-out-of-windows-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Those are all already disabled, unfortunately.

Comment: Tried the second method from the website? I added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Go to each item, accept or disallow, complete the entire list, OK, and then that screen will go away. I never see it again after I deal with each item.

Comment: That used to work, it doesn't anymore. It still comes back every couple fresh boots.

Comment: It works for me even new Insider builds. Open an admin command prompt and run DISM.exe /online /cleanup-image  /restorehealth and then restart and try again

Comment: @Morgan - Works for me on my 1909 VM

Comment: This worked for a couple months, but it's been back twice now. Never ending headache.